# How to avoid repetition in shell script for the below scene?

Tags: bash, shell

How to avoid repetition in shell script for the below scene?

I am trying to execute the shell script with a folder structure:

```
/tmp/demo/originals/*****contains 10 images****
/tmp/demo/originals/thumbnails/*****contains 3 images******
```

both the folders have image names same

Below, the code of resize.sh file located in `originals` folder:

```
path="thumbnails/*.jpg";
for file in *.jpg;
do
  imagename=$file;
  for file in $path;
  do
   conimagename=$file;
   batchname=${conimagename#*/}
   if [[ $batchname == $imagename ]];
   then
   echo $batchname 'already converted'
   else
   echo $imagename 'remaining'
   fi
  done
done
```

created the shell script in the folder `/tmp/demoresize/originals/`

creat

out put:

```
10.jpg remaining
10.jpg remaining
10.jpg remaining
1.jpg already converted
1.jpg remaining
1.jpg remaining
2.jpg remaining
2.jpg already converted
2.jpg remaining
3.jpg remaining
3.jpg remaining
3.jpg already converted
4.jpg remaining
4.jpg remaining
4.jpg remaining
5.jpg remaining
5.jpg remaining
5.jpg remaining
6.jpg remaining
6.jpg remaining
6.jpg remaining
7.jpg remaining
7.jpg remaining
7.jpg remaining
8.jpg remaining
8.jpg remaining
8.jpg remaining
9.jpg remaining
9.jpg remaining
9.jpg remaining
```

result should be:

```
10.jpg remaining
1.jpg already converted
2.jpg already converted
3.jpg already converted
4.jpg remaining
5.jpg remaining
6.jpg remaining
7.jpg remaining
8.jpg remaining
9.jpg remaining
```

Comment: What are the values of `conimagename` that `${conimagename#*/}` produces identical results for all three files?

Comment: it appears you're outputting in the inner loop when it should be saved for the outer loop.

Comment: Not related, but you can say `for conimagename in $path;` directly; you don't have to use a temporary variable for the loop only to assign it to another variable.

Comment: What is a "bellow scene"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you print something for every iteration of the inner loop. You need to print your result only once, which means you need to print it after the inner loop has finished. So preset a variable that indicates the file isn't found, and then set that variable if you find the file.

```
result='remaining'
for file in $path;
do
 conimagename=$file;
 batchname=${conimagename#*/}
 if [[ $batchname == $imagename ]];
 then
 result='already converted'
 fi
done
echo $imagename $result
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve can be accomplished with

```
for f in *.jpg; do 
   if [ -e thumbnails/$f ]; then 
      echo "$f already converted" ; else
      echo "$f remaining" ;
   fi;
done
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to loop by the way. Use the tools you have. 
Need to find all *.jpg files in you directories tree ?
 --> `find . -name *.jpg`

Duplicated ones are those which are already converted and the other one are remaining. 
Am I right ?

So we have the following scripts:

**To catch the remaining photos to convert** :

`find . -name \*.jpg -exec basename {} \; | uniq -u`

**To catch the already converted**:

`find . -name \*.jpg -exec basename {} \; | uniq -d`

PS: The repertory given to `find` is the current working dir but could be a parameter given to the script.

You can then use:

`for image in $(find . -name *.jpg | uniq -u);do
echo "$image remaining"
done`

I know I didnt really answer the question, but behind the shell language there is also a philosophy that is "don't reinvent the wheel". 
Keep it simple stupid. I wanted you to feel it. There are numerous tools. Mix them with pipelining and you've got the real shell killer feature.

PS: Don't use `${conimagename#*/}` prefer `basename $conimagename` . Be explicit in your naming. conimagename doesn't talk to me.

Comment: Since the files have numbers in their names, it should be obvious that `grep 1` is not the way to go, in this case 1.jpg will be reported as a photo to convert (based on the example). You may want to check the uniq manual, it has switches to print only unique or only duplicate lines. Instead of `-exec basename..` you should use -printf find option and avoid a unnecessary fork (not that find is appropriate in this case)

Comment: Ok I forgot the fact pictures' name can contains number. But it can be solved with an appropriate regexp no ? What about '^1' ? I'm no expert in regexp but i'm sure this can easily be solved.
Anyway,  you're right about uniq. I update the answer.